# Почему порядок вывода такой?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

Почему такой порядок вывода?

На второй строчке промис микротаска пораждает макротаску setTimeout, разве не должно быть

3 5 4 6?

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(3))
Promise.resolve().then(() => setTimeout(() => console.log(4)))
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(5))
setTimeout(() => console.log(6))

// Порядок вывода: 3 5 6 4
```

Comment: Чтобы исполнить `Promise.resolve()` тоже какое-то время нужно, пусть и самое минимальное, и только после этого запустится верхний `setTimeout`, поэтому у вас сначала отрабатывает нижний `setTimeout`, а потом уже верхний `setTimeout`

Comment: нашёл красивый сайт с пошаговым выполнением вашего скрипта: https://www.jsv9000.app/?code=UHJvbWlzZS5yZXNvbHZlKCkudGhlbigKICBmdW5jdGlvbiBwMygpIHsgY29uc29sZS5sb2coMyk7IH0KKTsKUHJvbWlzZS5yZXNvbHZlKCkudGhlbigKICBmdW5jdGlvbiBwNCgpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoCiAgICAgIGZ1bmN0aW9uIHQ0KCkgeyBjb25zb2xlLmxvZyg0KTsgfQogICAgKTsKICB9Cik7ClByb21pc2UucmVzb2x2ZSgpLnRoZW4oCiAgZnVuY3Rpb24gcDUoKSB7IGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKDUpOyB9Cik7CnNldFRpbWVvdXQoCiAgZnVuY3Rpb24gdDYoKSB7IGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKDYpOyB9Cik7